# Why is the Reflexive Property just about one number equal to the same one?

Tags: logic

Why do $10=10$ and $c=c$ belong in the Reflexive Property group?  I understand they're the same and equal but why?  Why does this happen?  Also $5+4=5+4$.  Just let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Equality (=) is defined as a relationship that is reflexive, symmetric and transitive so, by definition, it is part of the reflexive group. It doesn't matter if you're dealing with numbers or symbols, it is first and foremost a relationship between two elements of a group.

Comment: Huh? Mathematicians and philosophers usually aren't in the business of "defining equality."